# How to set same scale for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to compare subplots visually with ease. To do this, I want to set the same scale for all subplots.

My code works fine, and I'm able to plot subplots, but with their own scales. I want to maintain the scale on the x axis.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to have two subplots with the same xaxis, you can use the [`sharex`-keyword](https://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html) when you create the second axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)


t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)

ax1.plot(t, np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))
ax2.plot(t, np.cos(2 * np.pi * t))

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: This didn't work for me. All subplots had x ranging from -5 to 5, but the scales were all different. In this example, the subplots are so similar to each other that the scale didn't change.

Comment: @DavidEpstein if by the scale you mean the Y axis, you can set `sharey`. For example, you can first use the `ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=your_max_scale)` to set the ax1 scale, then for ax2 use the `sharey=ax1`. This way your Y axis scale will also be the same based on your data.

Comment: Having the same scale doesn't necessarily mean sharing the same axis, although the same axis ensures the same scale.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use subplots:

```
fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize = (10,8), sharex=True)

x = np.random.randn(1000)
x1 = x + 3
sns.histplot(x, ax = axs[0])
sns.histplot(x1, ax = axs[1])
fig.show()
```

[image]