# How to make that subplots created in a for loop share the same scale and xticks (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code snippet, to create 20 subplots, showing a line, with different markers. 
However, in y axis don't show the same scale, and they take part of some subplots, which makes the entire figure to look ugly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
markers = [".", ",", "o","v","^","<",">","s","p","P","*","h","H","+","x","X","D","d", "|", "_"]
num_subplots = len(markers)
fig = plt.figure()
for i, j in zip(range(num_subplots), markers): 
    try: 
        i +=1
        data = np.random.random(10)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(5,5,i)
        ax.plot(data, marker = j)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I found in this post some information regarding the sharex argument, which is useful, however I cannot implement this idea in a loop.

[How to set same scale for subplots in python using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975744/how-to-set-same-scale-for-subplots-in-python-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create the subplots first:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,5, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for marker, ax in zip(markers, axes.ravel()):
    try:
        data = np.random.random(10)
        ax.plot(data, marker=marker)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: wao! a better and more elegant solution. Sorry but sometimes this idea of axes within a figure is counteruntuitive for me :-/